# Antlr4 extremely simple grammar failing

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Antlr4 has always been a kind of love-hate relationship for me, but I am currently a bit perplexed. I have started creating a grammar to my best knowledge and then wanted to test it and it didnt work at all. I then reduced it a lot to just a bare minimum example and I managed to make it not work. This is my grammar:

```
grammar SwiftMtComponentFormat;

separator              : ~ZERO EOF;

ZERO                   : '0';
```

In my understanding it should anything except a '0' and then expect the end of the file. I have been testing it with the single character input '1' which I had expected to work. However this is what happens:

[image]

If i change the `~ZERO`to `ZERO` and change my input from `1` to `0` it actually perfectly matches... For some reason the simple negation does not seem to work. I am failing to understand what the reason here is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a parser rule `~ZERO` matches any token that is not a `ZERO` token. The problem in your case is that `ZERO` is the only type of token that you defined at all, so any other input will lead to a token recognition error and not get to the parser at all. So if you enter the input `1`, the lexer will discard the `1` with a token recognition error and the parser will only see an empty token stream.

To fix this, you can simply define a lexer rule `OTHER` that matches any character not matched by previous lexer rules:

```
OTHER: .;
```

Note that this definition has to go *after* the definition of `ZERO` - otherwise it would match 0 as well.

Now the input `1` will produce an `OTHER` token and `~ZERO` will match that token. Of course, you could now replace `~ZERO` with `OTHER` and it wouldn't change anything, but once you add additional tokens, `~ZERO` will match those as well whereas `OTHER` would not.